# Tomcat Spring Boot program not respecting group ownership of folder

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I'm running Tomcat as just a "portable", with bin/startup.sh. No services. It's also running on my ubuntu user, who has web-dat added to it.

My problem is, for some reason it's ignoring Tomcat/publicdata dictionary's group ownership which was set using (Rebooted the server/tomcat, no help):

```
sudo chgrp web-dat /home/ubuntu/Tomcat/publicdata/
sudo chmod g+s /home/ubuntu/Tomcat/publicdata/
```

Every file created should have the owner ubuntu, and the group web-dat. If I create a file using just a random Java application in that publicdata folder, it's assigned the web-dat group. Or any other application. Only when I create a file in that folder using my Spring boot application, powered by Tomcat, does it NOT set the group to web-dat.

Using Ubuntu22, Tomcat10, Java 21, and Spring Boot 3.2.0

Executed the following expecting Tomcat, who too is running under the ubuntu user, to create files in publicdata that would use the group web-dat.

```
sudo chgrp web-dat /home/ubuntu/Tomcat/publicdata/
sudo chmod g+s /home/ubuntu/Tomcat/publicdata/
```

Instead, said files do not contain the web-dat user. They just contain the user ubuntu.